# How to use python-docx to change the color of a particular text in office-word

Tags: text, python-docx

How to use python-docx to change the color of a particular text in office-word
Thank you very much!

I've tried a lot of solutions, and most of them just make the entire run with a particular text turn red

Most solutions like the ones below are not what I want：
`    from docx import Document

```
document = Document('path/to/your/document.docx')  


old_text = 'old'  
new_text = 'new'  

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:  
    for run in paragraph.runs:  
         if old_text in run.text:  
              run.text = run.text.replace(old_text, new_text)  

document.save('path/to/your/modified_document.docx')`
```